# Regex to capture both '?' and '%3f' in a javascript replace() method

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm terrible with `Regex`, can't find a suitable answer on Stack which works for this.

I have a string like this:

```
 var str = 'abc?def%3f999%3F^%&$*'
```

I only want to remove the following:

`?`, `%3f` and `%3F` (the entity codes for question marks)

I've tried this:

```
 var theQuery = str.replace([\\?]|\\%3f|\\%3F,'');
```

But this doesn't appear to be valid `regex`. What's a solution that will work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
var str = 'abc?def%3f999%3F^%&$*'
var theQuery = str.replace(/\?|%3f/gi, '');
//=> abcdef999^%&$*
```

- You need to use regex delimiters `/` and `/`
- You need to use global switch `g`
- No need to double escape
- No need to escape `%`

Comment: Was just waiting for the timer to allow me to. Someone weirdly downvoted both the question/answer and voted to close so SO didn't let me do anything for a while.

Comment: I don't know the intent of down-voter, its really weird. I have upvoted your question to remove -1